# Select nth element and perform string operation

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, replace

How can I select the value of the 2nd dd element in the HTML below? (edit: this is just a small list, the actual list is much longer).
And if possible remove the , from the value as well?

```
<dl class="field field-name-field-movie-genre field-type-taxonomy-term-reference field-label-inline clearfix">
    <dt>Genre</dt>
    <dd class="even">Love / Romance,</dd>
    <dd class="odd">Comedy,</dd>
    <dd class="even">Action</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 3):

Since it has the class 'odd', you should be able to use that as a selector:

```
$('.odd')
```

Or if you wanted to define it as a child of a field element, you could use :

```
$('.field .odd')
```

**Updated**

To select a specific element by position, you can use the [:nth-child()](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector :

```
$('.field :nth-child(2)')
```

Comment: Thanks. I asked it wrong: I do want to use the nth item selector, since this list is actually much longer. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
var e = $("dl dd:eq(1)");
e.text(e.text().slice(0,-1));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this should work

```
$('dl dd').eq(1).text().replace(/,/g,"");
```

Comment: It only works if the text has only one **,** at the end. With something like this: **Blue, Red and Green,**, it will not work as he wants

Comment: @letiagoalves I update the function, so now it will update all occurences of ","

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I guess he only wants to remove the "," at the end of the text, not all ocurrences. Ex: **Blue, Red and Green,** must become **Blue, Red and Green**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [:nth-child()](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) jQuery selector and JavaScript replace for string manipulation:

```
$('.field :nth-child(2)').val($('.field :nth-child(2)').val().replace(',', ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not directly answering the question but from what you've posted it would seem that it would be better to strip out the unwanted characters server-side rather than use javascript/jquery. This would make the page more easily cachable and result in better performance for users.

I assume the list is generated using an application using php or similar. Just add in a `string replace` filter to whatever function produces the html list.